# How to get the post ID when creating JS variables with localize_script

Tags: wp-localize-script

how do you set the current post ID as a JS variable with localize_script? It seems like the $post variable isn't availible in the functions.php file. When is it created? Do i have to add localize script to a hook? Which?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should declare `global $post;` before attempting to access this variable, but to answer your question regarding when it is created, the 'wp' action hook is the safest bet.

As such I'd suggest the following in your functions.php file as a simple solution

```
function my_localize_post_id(){
   global $post;
    wp_register_script( 'your_script'... /** other parameters required here **/ );
    wp_localize_script( 'your_script', 'the_name_for_your_js_object' , array( 'post_id'=>$post->ID ) );
}

add_action( 'wp', 'my_localize_post_id' );
```

Comment: Yes, I know I should use global. I was trying to run localize script directly in the functions file. But adding it to the wp hook worked great. Thanks!